# What is the difference in cache memory and tightly coupled memory

Tags: arm, cpu-cache

Due to being embedded inside the CPU The TCM has a
Harvard-architecture, so there is an ITCM (instruction TCM)
and a DTCM (data TCM). The DTCM can not contain any
instructions, but the ITCM can actually contain data.
The size of DTCM or ITCM is minimum 4KiB so the typical
minimum configuration is 4KiB ITCM and 4KiB DTCM.

It looks like tcm have same purpose as cache memory.

No. They didn't used the word cache in explanation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's ARM TCM memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797106/whats-arm-tcm-memory)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A cache uses access patterns to populate data within the cache.  It has extra hardware to track the backing address and may have communication with other system entities (SMP) to track when a cache line is **dirty** (someone else has written something to primary memory).

The 'TCM' (tightly coupled memory) is fast, probably SRAM multi-transistor memory, like the cache.  Both have a fast dedicated connection to the CPU.  However, the overhead to implement the TCM is far less than a cache.  Typically TCM is found on lower-end (deeply embedded probably Cortex-M) ARM devices.

Most CPU caches have a *lock down* feature which enables them to behave like the TCM.  However, the TCM does not have *on the fly* capabilities to buffer high use code and data.  Because of this, the TCM (and locked cache) is probably more deterministic which may help hard *real time* applications.

Comment: I am working on STM32F777II, was just wondering how can I force the linker to store some specified variables and structures in TCM/CCM only and not in the conventional RAM?

Comment: That depends on the linker you are using.  With gnu ld, read about [ld `memory` command](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_16.html#SEC16) which uses [section's region](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_21.html) or just specify the address with `AT`.  Also it depends on MMU or LMA/VMA issues.

Comment: TCM **may** also be addressed by DMA peripherals.  It is possible that a locked cache may allow this, but it is less likely.  Often it will depend on the bus structure, so it is possible that only a limited set of devices maybe supported on any SOC (with either case).

Comment: Many SOCs also have 'on-chip' RAM.  This is also often zero-wait state memory.  For any memory type, a 'zero wait' state is the fastest memory a CPU can work with.  It means the 'load-store' stage of the CPU is taking less time than the computational portions.  Some Cortex-M systems have both I/D TCM.  This is 'Harvard' architecture  which has **most** advantage if there is no cache.  So, read the data sheets for specifics on what TCM is doing in the system; but it is not the same as `cache` as noted in the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to test a ATCM and BTCM. Intentionally, by corrupting the TCM memory inside and I want to check whether CPU can make a relevant warning signal or operation. Especially, I'd like to use AXISCEN_ENABLE, then Cache will stop. so I can manipulate the inside of TCM. But I'm confused that if I make it dirty,then still valid for TCM TEST.

Comment: @Carter I think ATCM and BTCM are vendor specific.  I have seen ITCM and DTCM (for code/instruction and data).  It depends on the ARM; some are harvard and others von neumann.  I think you are better to ask a new question (and tag as verilog/VHDL as it sounds like you might have an FPGA/SOC type system).  Generally TCM are 'Cortex-M', but I am not really sure which system you are referring to.

Answer (score 10):

This is what I found that I feel is more concise and to the point.

Cache memory is implemented with on-chip memory and control logic. Tightly coupled memory is implemented with on-chip memory and a dedicated connection.

Tightly coupled memory has a fixed span in the address map. Cache does not live in the address map (.... well it kinda does.... just don't think of it as a physical memory) but instead serves as an intermediate between the processor and the memory to (hopefully) provide more efficient memory accesses.

Tightly coupled memory has deterministic access time. Accesses through the cache are not deterministic since the data will either live in the cache (hit) or the data must be fetched from main memory (miss).

Another

While both are very fast accessed memories, cache stores dynamically data/code which has been lately used in order to improve access speed, compared to standard memory connected to the global Avalon matrix. Every time a memory access is required, the processor checks if the required data is already present in the cache or must be newly fetched from memory; in the meantime, old unused cache data is being continously replaced with new data.
Tightly coupled memory is also a fast access memory, since it exploits a dedicated port, but it has static content: you decide what you need there and you specify it in the linker script.

Answer (score 3):

TCM has allocated address space so you can find it in the memory map. You can control the data that will be stored there already at link time. Just think of it as a normal system memory that has access times similar with cache. Usually the data from TCM is uncacheable.

Answer (score 2):

If we ignore the dual-configurable cache-cum-TCM, cache memory should be connected to Bus Interface (BIU) to connect external memory, whereas TCM aren't. Reason is TCM has original data by itself. Whereas cache is temporary storage (for speed) of external memory content.